# UITextfield text inside UITableViewCell disappearing on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm storing data into NSUserDefaults like so from each of my custom UITableView Cells:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < additionalClaimants; i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.table_view cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        UITextField* firstNameField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UITextField* employeeIDField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

        [defaults setObject:firstNameField.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"claimant%d_name",i+1]];
        [defaults setObject:employeeIDField.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"claimant%d_employeeID",i+1]];


    }
    [defaults setInteger:additionalClaimants forKey:@"total_add_claimants"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

I'm displaying the data in the UITableView like so in the cellForIndexPath method:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AdditionalClaimantsTableViewCell *cell = [self.table_view
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    NSString *claimant_name = [defaults objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"claimant%ld_name", (long)indexPath.row+1]];
    NSString *claimant_employeeID = [defaults objectForKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"claimant%ld_employeeID", (long)indexPath.row+1]];

    cell.txtField_eid.text = claimant_employeeID;
    cell.txtField_name.text = claimant_name;

    return cell;
}
```

Problem is when scrolling, the textfields that appear off view seem to lose the data in them.

Comment: You need to put back the code you removed in your edit. You do need it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is fine (subject to clarifying which version of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you want to use).  Your problem lies in the `for` loop where you try to save the values.  If you debug this `for` loop, you will find that `cell` is nil for any rows which are no longer on screen.  You need to find a way to save the values for each row before (or as soon as) it is scrolled off screen.  To do that, use the tableView delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Check and save the textField values in that method.

You will still need to save the values of any cells that are visible.  Your existing for loop will achieve that, but you could optimise it slightly by using the tableView's `visibleCells` property to get an array of cells, and iterate through that (which will avoid building the indexPath for rows which are not visible).

Comment: So cool! Thanks. Love learning new things to make my apps work!

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is when scrolling, the textfields that appear off view seem to
>   lose the data in them.

There really aren't such things as offscreen cells in table views. Not the way you're imagining them. Once a cell is scrolled offscreen it becomes the next cell to move onscreen again. It gets queued for reuse, and the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: call grabs it to use again to display another row in the table.

So never assign data to a table view cell except in the -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate call. Ever. Really. Trust me.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that what I'm doing? Assigning the data from the NSUserDefaults inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath? Also I updated the code by taking out the creating a cell if it doesn't exist.

Comment: In your -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: it looks like you are. But you're trying to get values out of cells that probably don't exist in the for loop above that call. So my guess is you're not storing the data the way you think you are.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. It's true for the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` method, not the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. The latter method can return `nil`.

Comment: Oops. You're correct. I've removed that bad info from my response.